# Zabbix monitor Antivirus products status

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

i'm trying to monitor all antivirus software installed on windows computer.

now, i do this:

zabbix_agentd.conf:

```
UserParameter=product_state,wmic /NAMESPACE:\\root\SecurityCenter2 PATH AntiVirusProduct GET /value | find "productState"
```

Zabbix Item:

```
Type: Zabbix Agent
Key: product_sate
type of information: Text
```

Zabbix Trigger:

```
Severity: Disaster
Expression: ({hostname:product_state.last(0)}<>266240) and ({hostname:product_state.last(0)}<>397312)
```

My problem occur when the agent sends the data with multiple values, like this:

```
productState=266240
productState=393472
```

In this case, i have a "Eset Antivirus" and "Windows defender" installed on client computer.

I think the solution is make a "discovery" in zabbix, but i don't know how to get the data from "wmic" command and monitor it.

please, can anybody helps me?

Thanks

Comment: Use LLD (low level discovery) in zabbix.

Comment: Thx, it's works fine.